# Cuando hago cambios en CSS se va al inicio de la página en el navegador usando Live server

Tags: css, vscode-live-server

buenas, mi problema es el siguiente: Al utilizar la extensión de VSCode "Live server" con el navegador Google Chrome, cuando estoy añadiendo diseños en CSS en la parte inferior de la página del navegador, al guardar los cambios se actualiza y en automático se pone en la parte superior de toda la página, y lo que quiero es que se quede en donde estoy trabajando (parte inferior de la página), es como si al actualizar se hace una especie de scroll hacia el inicio de la página. No sé si a alguien más le haya pasado y sepa como resolverlo. Espero y me puedan ayudar soy principiante en esto. Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Esto es porque usar live-server es lo mas similar a recargar la página, no estoy seguro pero hay una forma de evitarlo en la configuración del live-server, igualmente, por favor la próxima intenta hacer mejor la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

para resolver esto:

Vayan a: File -> Preferences -> settings

En settings Busquen Liver Server settings

clicken la casilla: Settings:Full Reload
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y luego reinicien el servidor, Esto me funcionó a mi.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo entiendo perfectamente lo que esta pasando, a mi me esta sucediendo igual, live server no deberia actualizar cuando hacemos cambios en archivos HTML o CSS, pero por algun motivo se esta disparando el reload con HTML y CSS, si le econtraste solucion por favor compartela, tengo un par de dias intentando solucionarlo y no lo consigo. Incluso desinstale la extension y hasta el VSC y al reistalar el comportamiento es igual.

Comment: Hola Leopoldo Martinez, bienvenido, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, si tienes alguna duda, crea tu propia pregunta, para recibir ayuda, Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/377729)